# How to embed my Vimeo video in my own site and allow only authenticated users to view?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I want to create app that allow users to upload their video to **my** Vimeo account. I want to hide these video from others. And allow only authenticated users of my app to view these videos.
My question is does Vimeo allow me to do? If yes, how can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! It can be done on a web site. I have recently seen this done on a tutorial site, using a privacy setting available per video. I trust this could also be done using an app, but it's possible the access permissons may be different.

Try checking this page for more details:
http://vimeo.com/help/faq/managing-your-videos/privacy-settings#what-do-the-different-privacy-settings-do

Pay particular attention to the following point, you can make a video exclusive to your site, but for a premium:

> You can select from the following privacy options for video embedding:
>
> Only on sites I choose (PLUS and Pro ONLY)

Comment: Thanks Tom. I also want to make this available for my web site too. Glad to hear that you already did :D

Comment: Is this really the answer?  I can imagine if someone can use Developer Tools, and modify the HTML markup on a "non-authenticated page", it would still play...  I think we need an authentication flow (eg. one time access tokens) in order to achieve this, or have I misunderstood anything?

Comment: @ThomasCheng is there any way of using one time access token in vimeo ?

Comment: Not that I know of

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it by following these steps:

1. Limit access to your video only with the private link.
2. Limit embed domain to your app/website domain

That`s it, now people will be able to view the video only through your embedded player and they will not be able to figure out the private link even with devtools

Comment: This does work. If you open the video-url from the embed-code in the browser it will display an error page. The irritating thing is that this error page also has a button "watch video on vimeo", which takes you to the video page on vimeo where you can actually watch the video ........... but only if you are the owner of the video.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by private link? I'm a little bit lost there. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the name of the settings have now changed so I had to play around with the options to find the right combination. This worked for me:

- Privacy
- Link -- Hide from Vimeo
- Embed -- Specific domain
- Embed -- Enter domain(s) to allow embedding

With these settings you cannot play the video directly in the browser via the link and you can only embed the listed domains.

[image: Screenshot of vimeo settings]

Comment: these exact options require a paid account by the way.