# Youtube & Vimeo paid/private content

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, vimeo, vimeo-api

Yesterday got a enquiry from a client to build a portal similar to LMS(Learning Management System) for uploading and watching videos.

**Features:**

- Admin can upload the videos
- Registered Users who have valid subscription can view these videos on the portal and not directly at Youtube or Vimeo

**My Question:**

- Can Youtube or Vimeo be used for hosting these videos?
- Videos should be accessible only from the portal and not be listed in Youtube or Viemo public directory.
- Does Youtube or Viemo have some paid/premium plan for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak on behalf of YouTube, but I can answer your question as it relates to Vimeo. I'd also assume that the same holds true for YouTube.

You can check out [this link](https://vimeo.com/help/faq/managing-your-videos/privacy-settings) which shows the Vimeo video privacy options. But you could easily prevent people from seeing it on Vimeo if you use `password` or `people I choose`.

Then through the [Vimeo api](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints) you could use the admin's Vimeo account credentials to request the videos specifically if your users have a valid subscription. If you use the admin Vimeo account client id and secret then you can request all the video's on that account (if it's a PRO account).

To clarify, requesting videos for the currently authenticated account through the API requires a Pro membership. Setting the privacy does not require PRO (at least not all of them do).

Comment: Can you please explain how it works? if i embed private video, it asks users to login to view, i don't want that, can we pre authenticate so that embedded links that the user sees are using admin creds, what i am asking is an example maybe of the authentication procedure you mentioned

Comment: You can generate an access token and use that with all requests. You can do this by going to [the Vimeo developer dashboard](https://developer.vimeo.com) and then clicking "My Apps" and then "Authentication". Then generate an access token. Refer to [this link](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start#getting-started-step2) for more info.

Comment: i tried playing around with this api using my access token, i only got json response, can i embed the video url of a private video with access token and have it play without having to input credentials?

Comment: How are you trying to play your video? I'll need some more information - I'm not sure why it's asking for your credentials if you're supplying an access token which acts as your credentials.

Comment: i am embedding my video, see example here https://jsbin.com/fiwuguwogu/edit?html,output , i got the embed link from the Vimeo Api's (of a private video i uploaded), but is there a way to pass a token to the vimeo embed link so the video starts playing?

Comment: You may want to check out [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20438497/how-to-embed-my-vimeo-video-in-my-own-site-and-allow-only-authenticated-users-to). I thought you were using the API to request a video and play it (in which case it'd work). Try changing the settings. Also you need to be PLUS or PRO. @dashron might be able to helper better than I can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. According to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos#Setting_Access_Controls), when uploading (or updating) a video in YouTube, you can specify access controls for that video. You can indicate whether a video can be listed in YouTube search results or displayed in any other way unless the user has a URL that links directly to the video. The permission for this setting will be denied if the video is either unlisted or private. If you set the value to denied for a public video, then that video will become an unlisted video.

Here's an example from [GitHub](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/resumable_upload.php) that uses statuses such as `"public"`, `"private"` and `"unlisted"`.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Youtube or Vimeo have some paid/premium plan for this?

Yes, Vimeo Plus plan would be enough.

> Videos should be accessible only from the portal and not be listed in
> Youtube or Viemo public directory.

Go to settings -> videos -> upload defaults

For privacy select 'Hide from vimeo.com'

And where it asks 'Where can your videos be embedded?' Enter your site domain (to prevet other sites from emddeing your video).

Now you can upload your videos and embed them to your site.

> Can Youtube or Vimeo be used for hosting these videos?

Vimeo would be a good fit for your requirements, YouTube not so much the best privacy setting for a video would be 'unlisted' so videos won't be appearing in search results they can be played directly on YouTube.